# What is this error message in C# programming?

Tags: c#

I received an error:

> 'MoveBall.Game' does not contain a definition for 'ballSpeedAxis1' and no extension method 'ballSpeedAxis1' accepting a first argument of type 'MoveBall.Game' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the beginning, there was no error when I tried to insert the value one by one.

```
int ballSpeedAxis1 = 1;
int ballSpeedAxis2 = 1;
...
int ballSpeedAxis10 = 1;
```

However, after I changed to a for loop as shown below.

```
var ballSpeedXAxis = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < ballSpeedXAxis.Length; i++)
{
    ballSpeedXAxis[i] = 1;
}
```

The error occurs on the following lines:

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedXAxis + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball1));
}
```

May I know how can I solved it?

Comment: I don't see where you're using `Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedXAxis + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball1));` so it's hard to say why there is an error. Please show **all** of the relevant code.

Comment: @Yuck Hi, do take a look at it again.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com..Thankyou for Asking the Q
may i know what is the error shown?

Comment: @Liu Jia Hui Seems you are New at this Account :D , Not the New to stackoverflow

Comment: @7-isnotbad Hi, the error is 'MoveBall.Game' does not contain a definition for 'ballSpeedAxis1' and no extension method 'ballSpeedAxis1' accepting a first argument of type 'MoveBall.Game' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @metadings Hi, this is the first error that I encountered.

Comment: well yes, c# tries to do something implicit ;) see @TimothyP's answer this may help you, so you can save ball's also into an array and then loop over both

Comment: can you show the Canvas.SetLeft() fn code

Comment: @7-isnotbad May I know what do you meant by fn code?

Comment: You must still be referencing ballSpeedAxis1 somewhere but have not changed that to use the new array.

Comment: can you add the Canvas.SetLeft() function code  to your Question ?

Comment: Your error message includes 'ballSpeedAxis1`.  Are you using `ballSpeedAxis1` instead of `ballSpeedXAxis` accidentally?

Comment: Canvas.SetLeft does not take an Array, You need to give `ballspeedXAxix` an index such as `Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedXAxis[0] + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball1));` Also what is calling the OnUpdate Event?

Comment: @HitLikeAHammer Hi, how should I do about referencing to the new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your [variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) is wrong. `ballSpeedXAxis` should be defined inside the class instead of inside the method that initializes it. Also, you cannot use var if you define a class-scoped variable. And it is weird that you don't use index inside OnUpdate method.

```
class MyClass {

    int[] ballSpeedXAxis = new int[10];

    MyClass() { // constructor
       for (int i = 0; i < ballSpeedXAxis.Length; i++)
       {
            ballSpeedXAxis[i] = 1;
       }
    }

    private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedXAxis[<some index here>] + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed ballSpeedXAxis to an array, yet in your OnUpdate you are trying to access it
as if it were a normal integer:

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
{
     Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedXAxis + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball1));
}
```

You must specify the index of the int in the array you whish to use

this.ballSpeedXAxis[0] for example.

Now you say the error is:

> 'MoveBall.Game' does not contain a definition for 'ballSpeedAxis1

If you're using VisualStudio, MonoDevelop or Xamarin Studio clicking the error
item in the Errors Window should take you right to the point in the code where you are still refering to ballSpeedAxis1.

You could even try to hit CTRL+F and enter 'ballSpeedAxis1' 
in the search box and search through the entire solution.

If you cannot find the location using either method,
then something might be out of sync and you should use the 'CLEAN SOLUTION' and 'REBUILD SOLUTION' functions of your IDE.

Comment: @TimonthyP Hi, I have tried this.ballSpeedXAxis[1]. However, I still received the same error.

Comment: Do they both reside in different class ?

Comment: @jparthj Hi, both are in the same class.